# vb.net create word table and align rows and text

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code to create a table in a word document:

```
'create the table
oDoc_detail_table = oDoc_detail.Tables.Add(oDoc_detail.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 1, 6)
'align the table in the center
oDoc_detail_table.Rows.Alignment = word.WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter
'set styles
oDoc_detail_table.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
oDoc_detail_table.Range.Font.Size = 8
'set width for columns
oDoc_detail_table.Cell(1, 1).Width = 80
oDoc_detail_table.Cell(1, 2).Width = 30
oDoc_detail_table.Cell(1, 3).Width = 330
oDoc_detail_table.Cell(1, 4).Width = 60
oDoc_detail_table.Cell(1, 5).Width = 60
oDoc_detail_table.Cell(1, 6).Width = 40
```

and i want to be able to set the height of ALL rows in the table (i am adding rows dynamically in my code)

also, i want the vertical alignment to be in the centre.

how can i do this in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the height property when you are adding the new rows? Is there a reason you need to set the height of all rows after they have been added?

If so, have you tried looping to set? This should execute quickly, applying all after the loop executes, eg:

```
For each r as Row in oDoc_detail_table.Rows
  r.Height = 100
Next r
```

Comment: it doesnt have to be once they are set - while they are being added would be okay

Comment: doing it as added, would that just be oDoc_detail_table.Rows.Height = 100

Comment: what would i Dim row as in that loop ?